# Too Dark When Rendering - No Light At All

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, lighting

I'm currently making a tree with branches and leaves etc., but for some reason, whenever I go from solid to rendering mode the textures that I applied come out extremely dark, which (I think) is caused by the lack of lighting. Can someone possibly help me? Here are some screenshots.

Here is the texture I applied to the trunk of the tree:

[image]

Here is the result after rendering:

[image]

Here are the nodes that I'm using:

[image]

Comment: Don't really get your problem. If you don't have any lightning, it will only be lighted by the world default environment color which is a dark grey, hence the dark render.

Comment: so how would I go about adding this? it seems that everytime i add a lamp in solid mode, then go to rendering mode, the lamp disappears

Comment: Add HDRI image and try

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the sun you have added to your scene should be enough to at least see your scene lit. The thing is that you have it turned off on the viewport. Turn it on by clicking the eye icon right next to it in the Outliner.

[image]

Comment: yeah, this fixed it i think. thanks dude.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is how 'Rendered' mode with Cycles works, it looks almost exactly the same as if you were hitting <kbd>F12</kbd> (or the 'Render' button). You can either not use 'Rendered' mode, add lights to the scene or enable ambient occlusion like so:

[image]

Comment: Ah, you sir, have saved hours of my time. much appreciated